# Issue with XSL script

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm very new to XSL, and I've tried this for a while but I'm just not getting it. I appreciate any guidance you can give me.

Current script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ExportXML">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="record">
      <xsl:element name="Job">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="field" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:element name="{@City}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

File to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <Document>
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute name="count">772</Attribute>
                    <Attribute name="duration">0:00:01.835</Attribute>
                    <Attribute name="mode">XML</Attribute>
                    <Content>
                        <ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
                            <record>
                                <field name="City">Chicago</field>
                                <field name="State">Illinois</field>
                                <field name="Title">Associate Product Manager</field>
                                <field name="Company">My company</field>
                                <field name="JobDescription">That job description</field>
                                <field name="Email">bsanford@invalidemail.com</field>
                            </record>
                        </ExportXML>
                    </Content>
                </Attributes>
            </Document>
        </ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected Output:

```
<xml>
    <Job>
        <City>Chicago</City>
        <State>Illinois</State>
        <Title>Associate Product Manager</Title>
        <Company>My company</Company>
        <JobDescription>That job description</JobDescription>
        <Email>bsanford@invalidemail.com</Email>
    </Job>
</xml>
```

Thank you for time in advance,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were issues with the input XML which have been fixed to make it well-formed. Still the input XML does not provide any information of the `namespace` associated with prefix `ns1` used for the `<getDocumentByKeyResponse>` element.

The main issue with the data not displayed in output is because of the fact that the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"` is not mapped in the XSL. This default namespace is associated with `<Export>` and all of its child elements. Request you to go through some tutorials on [XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) and why they are important.

Having said that, you need to make the following change in the XSLT to map the namespaces.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:t="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="t soapenv">
```

Access the elements using the template prefix `t` (used in the solution). Since the attribute `@name` becomes the element for all the `field` elements, you need to fix it accordingly.

```
<xsl:template match="t:record">
  <xsl:element name="Job">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:field" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="t:field">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wow, those few changes made that big of a difference! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/XML/2008/xsdl-exx/ns1"  soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:t="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"

    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs soapenv ns1 t"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::t:ExportXML"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="t:ExportXML">
        <xml>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="t:record"/>
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="t:record">
        <xsl:for-each select="t:field">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name='City'">
                    <City>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='City']"/>
                    </City>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='State'">
                    <State>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='State']"/>
                    </State>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='Title'">
                    <Title>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='Title']"/>
                    </Title>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='Company'">
                    <Company>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='Company']"/>
                    </Company>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='JobDescription'">
                    <JobDescription>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='JobDescription']"/>
                    </JobDescription>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@name='Email'">
                    <Email>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".[@name='Email']"/>
                    </Email>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
You can also do it by this way
```